# Error al agregar fila a tabla mediante javascritp

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola buenas tengo 2 tablas (adjunto imagen), mi idea es tomar una fila de una de ellas y enviarla a la otra, lo hago mediante javascript y la toma de datos la veo correcta, pero no hace el  append

Imagen de las Tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código en javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var price = $(this).data("price");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var button = $(this).data("button");
    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + id + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + price + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + button + "</td></tr>";
    alert(html);
    $(html).appendTo($("table:eq(0)").find("#table-body-venta-agregadas"));
});
```

el alert enviá lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código de mi segunda tabla

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body-venta-agregadas">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

sinceramente no veo fallas, pero espero que uno de ustedes si

Comment: Creo que estás muy confundido con respecto a lo que hace [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

Comment: por qué lo dices?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, intentas modificar el DOM (cosa que alert) no hace. A lo mejor me equivoco, pero ¿qué esperabas lograr con `alert()`?

Comment: nono, el alert era un flag para ver si el html estaba correcto, gracias por mencionarlo, pero es solo un flag

Comment: Lo que pasa es que `alert()` iba a mostrar la cadena **literalmente.** Si querías ver ese tipo de cambios tenías que usar algún método que modificara el DOM.

Comment: es que eso quería, saber si la cadena estaba impresa correctamente, si no se me había pasado algun / o estaba cerrando mal algun td o algo por el estilo

Comment: Oye mover elementos dentro de tablas o de una a otra se hace muy fácil con un pluggin de jQuery. [jQuery sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) permite mover elementos en regiones. Pero tus regiones pueden ser tablas. A mi me ha servido mucho para reorganizar tablas intercambiando elementos. No te doy ejemplo acá porque como respuesta ignoraría tu pregunta y no sería una respuesta válida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primera el ***alert()***, recibe como parámetro el mensaje que se debe mostrar en la ventana.

A lo que entiendo con tu codigo tu solución seria la siguiente.
en tu javascript tendrías que utilizar `$('#table-body-venta-agregadas').html(result)` con esto estarías imprimiendo el contenido en tu tabla, y dentro de tu codigo quedaria acomodado de la siguiente manera...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var price = $(this).data("price");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var button = $(this).data("button");
    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + id + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + price + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + button + "</td></tr>";

    $('#table-body-venta-agregadas').html(html)

    $(html).appendTo($("table:eq(0)").find("#table-body-venta-agregadas"));
});
```

Comment: disculpa, muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no me deja agregar mas de una fila, sabes que puede ser?
Edit: no es que no me deje agregar más filas, es que sobrescribe la que hay

Comment: ya has intentado solo ponerlo de esta manera ```$("#table-body-venta-agregadas").append(html);``` [enlace](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/insertar-codigo-sin-sobreescribir-874266/)

Comment: si, pero no funcionó, lo arreglé de la sig manera al inicio de la funcion agregué esta var
`var table = document.getElementById("table-body-venta-agregadas");`
y luego utilicé `table.innerHTML += html;` eliminando la linea `$('#table-body-venta-agregadas').html(html)`